# How to display a 2 terms graph in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In my ElasticSearch DB I have 2 fields:

1. Is a running number (1,2,3, etc)
2. Is a diferent number that depends on the first number (100, 50, 8, 4005 etc).

Now, I want to create a graph where the first number is on Y axis, and the second number is on the X axis.

How can it be done in Kibana?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `linechart`/`vertical bar chart`/etc and use a `Histogram Aggregation` on **first field** and appropriate `term aggregation` for **second field** (e.g. avg/sum)